# TabItem templates

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, tabitem

I have a tab control defined as this:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Documents}">
      <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TabItem>
                  <Button Content="Test button"/>
              </TabItem>
          </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I know that the Documents collection in the ViewModel is updated properly since I can see an empty tab header when I run my application, thus tab items are being created by the control. But for some reason there is no button in the tab item. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `TabItem` from your `DataTemplate` as at the moment you put `TabItem` within `TabItem`.

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Documents}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Test button"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

also if you want to your `Button` to appear in `Content` part and not in the `Header` then instead of `ItemTemplate` use `ContentTemplate`